# How to translate drop down menu django-filter

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-filter

I have many colors in my django-filter. color is a ForeignKey for Yarn model.

```
class YarnFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    color = django_filters.AllValuesFilter(name="color__name")

    class Meta:
        model = Yarn
        fields = [
                  'color',
                 ]
```

i want all color named to be translates in template.

```
<form action="" method="get">
    {{ filter.form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

i don't get where and how should i use django translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't done this myself, but I've used it on some projects.

Take a look at this third party if you haven't already: http://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/registration.html

The library doesn't require model changes, but it will add fields to your model based on the translations available in the django settings. (for example, if you have a field 'name', 'name_en', 'name_de' etc. will be added to your model).

More info and docs: http://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Because all you fields will be stored in the database, the translation will be done in the admin interface (http://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin.html).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, man, i'll try it. I thought there is some option out of box.